# Why is Joomla loading mootools-core and mootools-more twice?

Tags: jquery, mootools, joomla2.5

Built a simple site, can't seem to figure out why this is happening:

```
<script src="media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/plg_jblibrary/jquery/jquery.noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/mylocalfolder/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What could be causing mootools-core.js, core.js, and mootools-more.js to be pulling in twice with two different paths?  Where's a good place to search?  Considering the only thing I was thinking about using it for is a modal window (deactivated, no effect) this is a lot of junk to be loading for nothing.  I tried calling the `JHTML::_('behavior.modal');` a few times to see if it would continue to call additional copies but it doesn't.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is hard to say without being able to investigate more of the site (if you can post a link to the test site, that would be great!). I would also check the template's index.php file and see if any of the scripts were coded into there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has a built-in api to load mootools like this: `JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');` and it doesn't matter how many times you mention this, joomla will load `mootools-core.js` and `mootools-more.js` only once.

I guess one of your modules or plugins are adding mootools to output's head manually, it may be like this:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript("media/system/js/mootools-core.js");
```

Comment: Finally traced it down to Joomla Bamboo Library - handy plugin when configured right.  If not... ;)  Thanks!